# Hibernate dynamic parameters query

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have a query that need to use "dynamic" parameters set.
But coundn´t realize how to do it, i tried to not add the where string but it gives me erros because the parameter is seted.

Any tips?

```
String queryS = "select object(c) from "
                           + entityClassName + " as c " +
                            "where 1 = 1" ;

            if(codigoPaciente.compareTo("") != 0)
            {
                queryS += " and c.CodigoDoPaciente =:paciente";
            }
            if(codServicoPrincipal.compareTo("") != 0)
                queryS += " and c.codigoServicoPrincipal =:servico";
            if(data != null)
                queryS += " and c.codigoServicoPrincipal =:data";
            if(TipoServico.compareTo("") != 0)
                queryS += " and c.codigoServicoPrincipal =:tipoServico";


            Query query = em.createQuery(queryS);
            query.setParameter("paciente", codigoPaciente);
            query.setParameter("codigoServicoPrincipal", codServicoPrincipal);
            query.setParameter("data", data);
            query.setParameter("tipoServico", TipoServico);


            return query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting your parameters inside if conditions... Maybe set the parameter for each string you concatenate?

```
if(codigoPaciente.compareTo("") != 0)
            {
                queryS += " and c.CodigoDoPaciente =:paciente";
            }

Query query = em.createQuery(queryS);

// etc etc...
if(codigoPaciente.compareTo("") != 0)
    query.setParameter("paciente", codigoPaciente);
```

Comment: Another point; if you remove the WHERE clause and keep concatenating AND's without checking if some condition has already been concatenated you will have a criteria that starts with <nothing> AND <something>. This will give you an error of course.

Comment: Can´t set the parameter on the IF that build the query becausethe object "QUERY" doesn´t exists yet

Comment: The if is intended to be used after you create the query object obviously.

Comment: This solution violates DRY -- how can we define the query and set params at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than doing a bunch of string concatenation to create a query, the [criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html) could be used to construct the query in a more "safe" manner.  Then you could add the condition and the value in a single conditional check.

Comment: I agree with joel on this.

Comment: I only partially agree with myself. The criteria api is no joy to work with.

Comment: It may be a pain, but avoiding concatenating stuff usually pays off in the long run...

Comment: I was trying to avoid the criteriaAPI....but it seams that that is the only way to do that

Comment: See QueryDSL. Strongly typed dynamic queries without the pain of the criteria API. http://blog.mysema.com/2010/04/querydsl-as-alternative-to-jpa-2.html